# cakephp model associations - find other child of parent model

Tags: cakephp

I have associations:

- Product -> hasMany -> ProductOption
- Product -> hasMany -> ProductImage

I want to find the product data including ProductImage with the ProductOption.id

When I do this:

```
$this->Basket->Product->ProductOption->find('first',array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Product' => array(
            'ProductOption' => array(
                'conditions' => array('ProductOption.id = '.$id)
            ),
            'ProductImage'
        )
    )
));
```

I get this:

```
array(
    'ProductOption' => array(
        'id' => '46',
        'product_id' => '9',
    ),
    'Product' => array(
        'id' => '9',
        'name' => 'Some product',
    )
)
```

Which is most of what I want but without 'ProductImage' included. How do I get this in the array?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using too much recursion. If you're using Containable on Product, make the query on it, not ProductOption, like this:

```
$this->Basket->Product->find('first',array(
  'contain' => array(        
    'ProductOption' => array(
            'conditions' => array('ProductOption.id = '.$id)
    ),
    'ProductImage'
  )    
));
```

And no need to use Product on 'contain' array, it's already guessed.

(I didn't try this, but almost sure)

Comment: Actually this finds the correct ProductOption but doesn't give any where clause to the Product model: its query is (WHERE 1 = 1)